# Set items offset in recyclerView for ability to place one above other

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I use recyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and I need to do something like this
(one items over other)

[image: http://take.ms/kU8Zv]
I think that this can be done by overriding a few methods in LayoutManager, but i don't know which of them.
How i can to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found this solution, I hope it will help someone
https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
            RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        if (mDivider == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (parent.getChildPosition(view) < 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (getOrientation(parent) == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
            outRect.top = mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        } else {
            outRect.left = mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx, but ItemDecorator doesn't suit me, cause' next element is not created until you reach the end of the previous one, this can be seen a sharp appearance of items that have +1 position

Comment: You can also define multiple layout in recyclerview , visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type